# importrange query with date range last few months only

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i am using a importrange function with specific columns,
what i want is to pull data only for last few months from today. you can see in link below, formula is in A2. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WQtCLIM6GKOnOHfOzrAvqmIS9MEuO77UxGUS2_vz5pw/edit#gid=1546583511)

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("google sheet url", "Collection!A4:AG"),"select Col4, Col9",0)

You can see what i want has been described in column C, Column A ranges dates from 2019 to 2022 but i want to import only data from last few months from today.

Answer (score 1):

Add `where` condition to query function to remove null cells and filter last four months data. Try-

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("13o5oRHXJOns3Onnr9L72m9BJVXXG58ukGJh7aUO8fTM", "Collection!A4:AG"),
"select Col4, Col9 where Col9 is not null and Col4 >=date '" & TEXT(TODAY()-120,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'",0)
```

See you gs sheet name `harun24hr`.

Comment: worked but creating another issue 
I have a column were it consist of text and numbers but query renders numbers as text.